# Stuck in lasso mode

Tags: selection-tools

I'm stuck in lasso mode, thinking I must have pressed something by accident...

In Object Mode, everything appears to work fine, and 'W' will cycle through the select modes as expected.

In Edit Mode, the default select tool is stuck on Lasso (previously stuck on Circle). I can manually select Box Select or Circle Select by holding left-click or using hotkeys, but then it jumps right back to Lasso as soon as I click off. And for some reason 'W' will not allow me to cycle through the select modes, while in Edit Mode.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: What happens if you long press the top button in the toolbar on the left? Also, if you start a new file does the problem persist?

Comment: Where is the cursor when you're trying to use the W key? - It's working fine here in the current 3.4.1 version.

Comment: Incidentally, if you have selected the Circle option with the C key from another selection mode you'll need to press Esc to get back out of it.